# Calculate average with assigned values SQL

Tags: sql, sybase

Assume I have a table and it has the following columns:

assignment_id, employee.id, employee_salary and employee_performance

(assignment_id - int, employee.id - int, employee_salary - int, employee_performance - varchar).

The column employee_performance consists of the following values: excellent, good, average, bad, null.
I want to assign integers to the values and calculate average performance of an employee across different jobs. How can I do that?

For example, some employee has completed two assignments and his results are: excellent and good. I assign 10 to excellent and 9 to good and receive an average of 9.

```
assignment_id, employee.id, employee_salary employee_performance
1                   1            100,000          excellent
2                   1            100,000          excellent
3                   1            100,000          good
4                   4             50,000          good
5                   3             75,000          null
```

```
Null means that an assignment is not yet completed.
```

I want to assign integers to employee_performance. For example, excellent - 10, good - 9, etc.

Result should:

```
eployee.id         average_performance
1                       9,7
3                       9
```

epmployee.id = 4 is not included, as he does not have completed assignments.

Comment: Can you supply sample data and desired results?  Are you looking to average performance ratings per employee?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `case`.  Something like this:

```
select employee_id,
       avg(case when employee_performance = 'excellent' then 4.0
                when employee_performance = 'good' then 3.0
                when employee_performance = 'average' then 2.0
                when employee_performance = 'bad' then 1.0
            end) as avg_performance
from table
group by employee_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a 2 column table that contains each performance (i.e. excellent, good, etc) and its corresponding value.

```
------------------------------
|performance     |      value|
------------------------------
|excellent       |       10  |
------------------------------
|good            |       9   |
------------------------------
```

Once you have that table you can do a simple join and group by to get the average value per employee.

```
select id, avg(pv.value) 
from employees e
left join performance_values pv 
  on pv.performance = e.employee_performance
group by id
```